# Tag burnination request: [c++primer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [c++primer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bprimer) seems to be far too specific and refers to mainly exercise-type questions.

Tag wiki:

> A book written by Stanley B. Lippman, Josée Lajoie and Barbara E. One of the best books for C++ beginners.

There are currently 7 questions with this tag.

Comment: 7 questions: all are by sub-500 rep users (in fact, all but one are by sub-150 rep users). Someone with full editing privileges can wipe that out in 2 minutes.

Comment: Scratch that. No editing privileges needed: burnination complete.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image: Burninated]

I went through all of the questions in the tag and overhauled them, fixing spelling, grammar, and formatting. I also generalized them so that they can, for the most part, stand on their own outside of the context of the book.

The [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bprimer) has been removed from all 7 questions and deleted from the system.