# Is 'primer' a meta-tag? Burninate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, meta-tags

We already have [Tag burnination request: [c++primer]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268253/tag-burnination-request-cprimer) - but there's still [primer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primer)... *If you are using this tag, it is a good indication that you are asking a question that does not belong here.* - kill it with fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tag has been removed from all posts. It will cease to be within 24 hours, when the dead tag script runs.

Comment: *today a Lizard breathed the Cleansing Fire...*