# Burninating [real-world-haskell] is guaranteed to have no side effects

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [real-world-haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real-world-haskell) was created for questions related to the book by the same name as indicated by the tag wiki.  Not all questions using this tag appear to be related to the book, though (code that goes into production is *real world*, amirite?).

> Questions about O'Sullivan, Goerzen & Stewart's Real World Haskell book published by O'Reilly, and available free online from the authors at http://book.realworldhaskell.org/

Related:

- [Tag burnination request: [c++primer]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268253/tag-burnination-request-cprimer)
- [The learn-c-the-hard-way tag just seems no good to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291351/the-learn-c-the-hard-way-tag-just-seems-no-good-to-me)

Comment: Wait... people use "real-world" to mean prod code? seriously?.... man, our fellow devs make me sad sometimes....

Comment: @Patrice some people have learned to skip haskell audits, because, weird...

Comment: @Patrice It's not that depressing - most of the questions unrelated to the book seem to be random or tangential doubts people happened to have while going through it ([boat reading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about)?).

Comment: @Braiam The Haskell language exists just to populate audits in the Stack Overflow Close Vote Review Queue... didn't you know?

Comment: You want to kill the tag because its been misused?

Comment: @Carcigenicate No, I want to kill the tag because it is a meta tag like all of the other tags that we've burned that are related to books.

Comment: Sounds like a purely functional improvement to me.

Comment: @Patrice I assume they use it to mean stuff other than toy applications. Haskell has a stereotype (true or otherwise) of not actually being used for actual applications.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: provided `true` isn't ⟂, then `true || otherwise ≡ True`, because [the Haskell Prelude defines `otherwise = True`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:otherwise), which proves that the stereotype is correct. (Note that I've used referential transparency to be sure whatever `true` is, its evaluation won't meddle with the value of `otherwise`.) However, if you actually meant `true or otherwise`, then it's a function `true :: ([Bool]->Bool) -> Bool -> Bool`, which (thanks to lazyness) might not even consider the `otherwise` case!

Comment: @leftaroundabout - wow, that's exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: @leftaroundabout you should join an honor society.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[real-world-haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/real-world-haskell) has been merged to [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) - so syn has been created.